# ¿Cómo ingresar una fecha en una clase?

Tags: java, date, formato

intento ingresar una fecha pero me dice que no puedo convertir un string a Date.

```
per.setFecha_nacimiento("20-07-1998");     <--- cual es el formato indicado?
```

gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu variable fecha_nacimiento es tipo Date entonces tienes que mandarle un objeto tipo Date y no un String. Utiliza:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "20-07-1998";
try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            per.setFecha_nacimiento(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: A eso, hay que agregar que puede ser java.util.Date o java.sql.Date.